# How to use Tkinter's 'file' variable across different functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm using Python 2.7. I'm also using a library known as id3reader to get metadata from mp3 files. If I use this code:

```
import tkFileDialog
import id3reader

file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
id3r = id3reader.Reader(file)
print(id3r.getValue('performer')
```

everything works just fine, and the artist of the song's name will be printed out in the console.

However, I am trying to do this across different functions. So if I use this code:

```
import tkFileDialog
import id3reader

def Load(self):
  file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile()

def Display(self):
  id3r = id3reader.Reader(file)
  print(id3r.getValue('performer')
```

I get an error coming from within the id3reader script. If I use:

```
self.file
```

or

```
fileName = file
global fileName
```

I get a global variable not defined error.

How would I be able to use the built-in 'file' variable across different functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing a bunch of different things.

First, the built-in `file` variable is the actual type of file objects. You don't want to use that, you're trying to hide it with the filename you got back from `askopenfile()`.

And `file` is not a Tkinter variable—neither the builtin, nor the one you're creating, have anything to do with Tkinter.

The reason your code isn't working is that, inside the `Load` function, when you write `file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile()`, you're creating a local variable. That local variable hides the name of the global variable of the same name, until the function exits, at which point it goes away.

Your attempt to use `self.file` is a great solution—except you don't have any classes. If you want to learn about how to use classes in general, and the idiomatic way to use them with Tkinter in particular, that's a great thing to learn, but it's too much to teach in a StackOverflow answer, and Python already comes with a great tutorial.

If you want to use a global variable, you can do that, but (a) you have to use `global file`, not `global fileName`, if you want `file` to be global, and (b) you have to put that *inside the `Load` function*, not at the top level. If you do both of those, then that `file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile()` will now reassign the global variable `file`, instead of hiding it with a local variable, so the value will still be available once you're done, to any other function that wants to access it.

However, a better solution is to not try to share a global variable. Just `return` the value, and have the caller hold onto it and pass it into `Display`. Since I can't see the code you're using to call those functions, I'll have to make something up, but hopefully you can understand it and apply it to your own code:

```
def Load():
    return tkFileDialog.askopenfile()

def Display(file):
    id3r = id3reader.Reader(file)
    print(id3r.getValue('performer')

f = Load()
Display(f)
```

Comment: What if I'm trying to put it into a label by self.artistLabel["text"] = "Artist: {}".format(self.Display)? @abarnert

Comment: Because when I'm trying to do that, I keep getting the error: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment. I usually know what causes this error, and I've done all of the fixes I can think of, but I still can't get it to work? @BryanOakley

Comment: @HunterWatkins: You can't use `self` unless you create a class, and move your code into methods of that class. As I said in the answer, you're not going to be able to learn how to do that from an SO answer, but the official Python tutorial and the Tkinter tutorial are both very nice.

Comment: @HunterWatkins: Meanwhile, the `'NoneType' object does not support item assignment` error can only mean one thing: you've written `spam[eggs]`, and `spam` is `None`. In Tkinter, that often means you've done something like `spam = Button(…).pack()`; since `pack()` returns `None`, this means you've lost the reference to the `Button` object, and instead have a reference to `None`.

Comment: I am using classes. But nonetheless, I found out what I was doing wrong and got it working. Thanks for all your help. @abarnert